# Adding foreman on passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, nginx, passenger, foreman

So far I had a simple application that only required the classic `rails server` to boot.

I have recently added the `react_on_rails` gem and it requires to boot a nodejs server to handle webpack and javascript stuff.

So I understand I need this `foreman` gem that is capable of managing several processes. So far so good, but then I'm still having a few problems understanding and deploying this enhanced app to my production environment (Phusion Passenger on Apache/Nginx)

So several questions :

- Does passenger handle the transition from `rails s` to `foreman start -f Procfile.dev` automatically ?
- If `no` then where do I setup things so passenger works ?
- Side question : almost all google results refer to `puppet` when looking for `foreman on passenger`. Anyone could explain what `puppet` does in 1 line and if I really need it in production ? So far everythings runs smoothly on localhost with the `foreman start -f Procfile.dev` command so I don't know where this is coming from...

I am deploying my application to the Amazon Cloud using Capistrano, and I was expecting to have the rails + nodejs setup on every autoscaled instance (and Passenger would graciously handle all that). Am I thinking wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

In our production environment we use [eye](https://github.com/kostya/eye) to manage other processes related to the rails app. (Passenger will run from `mod_passenger` while the workers are controlled by eye)

And here is an example of how to start 4 concurrent [queue_classic](https://github.com/QueueClassic/queue_classic) workers:

```
APP_ROOT = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
APP_NAME = File.basename(APP_ROOT)

Eye.config do
  logger File.join(APP_ROOT, "log/eye.log")
end

Eye.application APP_NAME do
  working_dir File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  stdall 'log/trash.log' # stdout,err logs for processes by default
  env 'RAILS_ENV' => 'production' # global env for each processes
  trigger :flapping, times: 10, within: 1.minute, retry_in: 10.minutes

  group 'qc' do
    1.upto(4) do |i|
      process "worker-#{i}" do
        stdall "log/worker-#{i}.log"
        pid_file "tmp/pids/worker-#{i}.pid"

        start_command 'bin/rake qc:work'

        daemonize true
        stop_on_delete true
      end
    end
  end
end
```